# Spacy Extracting mentions with Matcher

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy-3

everyone I am trying to match a sentence into a bigger sentence using Spacy rule-matcher, but the output is empty.

```
import spacy 
from spacy.matcher import Matcher 
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
doc1 = nlp("DUMMY TEXT CafeA is very generous with the portions. DUMMY TEXT DUMMY TEXT")
pattern = [{"ENT_TYPE": "ORG"}, {"LEMMA": "be"}, {"POS": "ADV", "OP": "*"}, {"POS": "ADJ"}]
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("mentions",[pattern])
for mid, start, end in matcher(doc1):
    print(start, end, doc1[start:end])
```

The idea of the rule is to match the "*CafeA is very generous with the portions.*" bit, but I do not get any result. What is the correct way to do this in spacy?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces `2 6 CafeA is very generous` when I run it on my machine (Windows 11 64-bit, Python 3.10.9, spaCy 3.4.4) using both the `en_core_web_md` and `en_core_web_trf` pipelines. As a side note, "CafeA" is not tagged as an organisation when using `en_core_web_sm`, and therefore the pattern does not match.

If you want include "with the portions", you'll need to expand the pattern to include the appropriate PoS tags (i.e. `ADP` ([adposition](https://universaldependencies.org/u/pos/all.html#al-u-pos/ADP)), `DET` ([determiner](https://universaldependencies.org/u/pos/all.html#al-u-pos/DET)) and `NOUN` ([noun](https://universaldependencies.org/u/pos/all.html#al-u-pos/NOUN)) respectively). For example:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
doc1 = nlp("DUMMY TEXT CafeA is very generous with the portions. DUMMY TEXT DUMMY TEXT")
pattern = [{"ENT_TYPE": "ORG"}, {"LEMMA": "be"}, {"POS": "ADV", "OP": "*"}, {"POS": "ADJ"}, {"POS": "ADP"}, {"POS": "DET"}, {"POS": "NOUN"}]
for tok in doc1:
    print(tok.text, tok.pos_)
    print(tok.ent_type_)
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("mentions", [pattern])
for mid, start, end in matcher(doc1):
    print(start, end, doc1[start:end])
```

Matches and prints the following:

```
2 9 CafeA is very generous with the portions
```

If you're getting unexpected results with the matcher, try restarting your IDE or clearing any cached/stored variables.